# Bitmap to black and white sometimes crashes because of out of memory

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have this function to convert a bitmap into black and white.

```
public static Bitmap convertColorIntoBlackAndWhiteImage(Bitmap orginalBitmap) {
    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);

    ColorMatrixColorFilter colorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
    Bitmap blackAndWhiteBitmap = orginalBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(colorMatrixFilter);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(blackAndWhiteBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(blackAndWhiteBitmap, 0, 0, paint);

    return blackAndWhiteBitmap;
}
```

In some devices, sometimes it crashes with a

```
W/System.err(16049): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
W/System.err(16049):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCopy(Native Method)
W/System.err(16049):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.copy(Bitmap.java:479)
```

Any ideas ? :P

Comment: How big is the bitmap?

Comment: It's a PNG of about 3 or 4K ... very small ! but there's a bunch of them in the screen about 20 or 30 ... not so many)

Comment: No, how big is the bitmap, not the file - width and height?

Comment: 60x90 pixels ... small ones ;-)

Comment: Strange.  They only need about 21K of RAM each.  30 of them is only, what, about 600K.  Are you sure you are not loading a large bitmap somewhere?

Comment: The app has a lot of images around and everywhere, but the app is always crashing (when it crashes) at that point, converting little PNG's to black and white

Comment: Then you need to understand how bitmaps are loaded into memory - "a lot of images".  All bitmaps are stored on the heap, which is limited jn size regardless of how much memory a device has.  You cannot just loaded images haphazardly.  You need to understand how to use them.

Comment: I use gc always in each activity ...

Comment: You shouldn't.  Read about why calling gc is useless, especially when dealing with bitmaps.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/20919167/1847645